# SVG Images displaying different colours in Safari when refreshing page

Tags: angular, svg

I am working on an Angular application that uses a range of SVG images on various pages. I am having a problem where these images do not always display in the correct colours when viewing them in Safari. The images look fine if I load the page that the images are on originally, but when I navigate from one page to the next, some of the images do not display in the correct colours. See example below:

[image]
Correct

[image]
Incorrect

This only seems to happen in Safari. I am using version 12.0.3 of Safari. The iMac I am using is fairly old and is largely only used for testing our software in IOS, so not sure if that might have an impact on what I am seeing.

Here is how the SVG appears in my code. I am adding it in as a mat-icon through the Angular framework:

```
<mat-icon _ngcontent-lvp-c20="" class="vectorImage fade-in mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-no-color" id="vector4" role="img" svgicon="vector4" aria-hidden="true" ng-reflect-ng-style.gt-sm="[object Object]" ng-reflect-svg-icon="vector4" style="bottom: 100px;"><svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1730.4 595.28" fit="" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#0d113a;}.cls-2{fill:#f7f7f7;}.cls-3{fill:#a3b2c9;}.cls-4{fill:#ebcfb1;}.cls-5{fill:#3b4559;}.cls-6{fill:#eac4b0;}.cls-7{fill:#ea1e30;}.cls-8{fill:#d6e8f4;}.cls-9{fill:#616c78;}.cls-10{fill:#deedf1;}.cls-11{fill:#e6e6e5;}.cls-12{fill:#363d52;}.cls-13{fill:#363940;}.cls-14{fill:#dedede;}.cls-15{fill:#5d7abc;}.cls-16{fill:#c48270;}.cls-17{clip-path:url(#clip-path);}.cls-18{fill:#fff;}.cls-19{fill:#bdbfbf;}.cls-20{fill:#e1e1e0;}.cls-21{fill:#333d4f;}.cls-22{fill:#575759;}.cls-23{fill:url(#linear-gradient);}.cls-24{fill:url(#linear-gradient-2);}.cls-25{fill:#ac202d;} </style><clipPath id="clip-path"><path class="cls-1" d="M1296.09,226.2s-31.79,40.57-47.69,50.44h0a4,4,0,0,0-2.44,1.68,9.1,9.1,0,0,0-1.29,3.53,36,36,0,0,0-.7,6.54,11.8,11.8,0,0,0,.88,5.34,5.11,5.11,0,0,0,4.2,3.06c2.45.06,3.52-2.28,4-5.25,8.47-5.79,31.43-21.68,33.22-25,2.19-4.13,13.7-40.31,13.7-40.31Z"></path></clipPath><linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="1114.69" y1="270.62" x2="1237.38" y2="270.62" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#1d3557"></stop><stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#1d3557"></stop><stop offset="0.39" stop-color="#14253c"></stop><stop offset="0.75" stop-color="#0d1929"></stop><stop offset="1" stop-color="#0b1522"></stop></linearGradient><linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="494.25" y1="267.88" x2="557.74" y2="267.88" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"></linearGradient></defs><path class="cls-2" d="M1462.42,440.45H1232l17.92,36.34-17.19,5.1-35.48-41.44H1148.3l-4.8,40.18h-17.31l-9.11-40.18H452.91c-34.31,0-62.38,7.62-62.38,16.94,0,6.46,13.46,12.1,33.14,15H355.2c-34.32,0-62.39,7.63-62.39,16.95s28.07,16.94,62.39,16.94h6.22c-9.29,3-14.93,6.79-14.93,11V524c0,9.32,28.07,16.94,62.39,16.94h993.35c34.32,0,62.39-7.62,62.39-16.94v-6.78c0-8.62-24-15.79-54.75-16.82a60.56,60.56,0,0,0,15.55-3.32c10.57-4.18,11-10.55,5.87-15.82-3.35-3.41-8.72-6.12-22-7.14l53.15.23c34.31,0,62.39-7.62,62.39-16.95s-28.08-16.94-62.39-16.94"></path><polygon class="cls-3" points="548.01 310.47 558.42 334.47 559.4 402 580.8 474.63 570.85 479.04 527.18 394.71 522.21 368 520.24 311.74 548.01 310.47"></polygon><polygon class="cls-3" points="497.62 315.85 496.8 386.62 510.14 477.86 520.39 477.86 526.87 393.67 540.9 309.48 497.62 315.85"></polygon><polygon class="cls-1" points="494.48 243.25 473.68 222.93 465.75 232.32 487.01 264.61 494.92 267.17 528.63 240.29 519.61 221.88 494.48 243.25"></polygon><path class="cls-1" d="M569.77,270.47C561.35,233.32,545.05,219,545.05,219l-27.24,1-16.4,56.79-18.28,74.69c12,1.51,85,11.25,85,11.25S578.34,308.3,569.77,270.47Z"></path><path class="cls-2" d="M525.33,223.4,496.69,337.93l-2.34,15,35.67,4.7s-1.41-54.85-.94-62.16,5.76-23.13,6.57-40.17c.47-9.86,3.61-27.57,1.41-33.33Z"></path><polygon class="cls-4" points="1406.21 156.3 1404.72 145.28 1409.4 144.45 1412.09 151.77 1414.12 150.34 1414.24 159.92 1409.49 161.45 1406.21 156.3"></polygon><polygon class="cls-3" points="1476.09 214.37 1434.17 202.87 1415.29 156.67 1406.02 160.18 1416.22 219.67 1464.35 245.27 1476.09 214.37"></polygon><rect class="cls-1" x="1468.1" y="326.48" height="14.78"></rect><polygon class="cls-1" points="1431.16 320.3 1422.06 369.06 1421.31 392.98 1441.01 474.24 1453.32 471.78 1448.4 405.29 1468.1 341.26 1468.1 326.49 1431.16 320.3"></polygon><polygon class="cls-1" points="1499.26 331.67 1452.47 343.98 1472.27 479.42 1481.26 479.42 1486.94 405.54 1499.26 331.67"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="1443.05 475.93 1433.65 485.88 1436.36 490.92 1455.76 481.61 1452.18 474.24 1443.05 475.93"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="1472.43 482.58 1460.85 489.86 1462.21 495.42 1483.32 491.25 1481.7 483.23 1472.43 482.58"></polygon><path class="cls-6" d="M1441,178.41c8,.59,15.44-6,23.29-4.34,5.11,1.06,9.14,5.59,10.7,10.69a12.69,12.69,0,0,1,.27,7.34,12.19,12.19,0,0,1-2.31,4.15,17.3,17.3,0,0,1-4.8,4.06,31.46,31.46,0,0,0,3.42,4.53l-11,4.23-2.44-6.34a16.67,16.67,0,0,1-3.29-.5,19.08,19.08,0,0,1-13.41-14.17,37.09,37.09,0,0,1-.39-9.65"></path><polygon points="1442.96 180.82 1467.64 177.89 1472.43 196.74 1479.4 191.21 1475.81 160.36 1440.98 159.61 1425.9 168.46 1426.54 177.32 1440.02 186.4 1442.96 180.82"></polygon><path class="cls-3" d="M1452.54,212l29.31-11.63s13.69,28.93,25.53,70.38-3.82,99-3.82,99-81.73-16.69-95.14-19.32l26.45-82.89Z"></path><path class="cls-7" d="M1456.69,123.5l-9-10.93-.3,0c-.44-1.26-.87-2.53-1.31-3.79l-6.87-20c-2-5.87-3.28-15.65-10.76-16.59l-71.14-8.9a20.55,20.55,0,0,0-20,10l-15.07,24.68-1.19-.14-24.77,4.53a24.57,24.57,0,0,0-16.41,20.19l-1.75,14,180.63,22.6,2.49-19.91a20.63,20.63,0,0,0-4.53-15.64"></path><path class="cls-8" d="M1388.68,103.14l47.46,5.94-7.46-27.9a3.43,3.43,0,0,0-2.86-2.57l-33.55-4.2Z"></path><path class="cls-8" d="M1384.15,73.4,1357,70a15,15,0,0,0-14.6,7.28L1331,95.93l49.58,6.2Z"></path><path class="cls-9" d="M1427.75,79.56a3.55,3.55,0,0,1,.93,1.62l2.06,7.69.21.15-2-7.63a3.59,3.59,0,0,0-1.16-1.83"></path><path class="cls-10" d="M1414.42,77.36c4.9,3.5,9.85,6.93,14.76,10.41l1.56,1.1-2.06-7.69a3.55,3.55,0,0,0-.93-1.62,3.31,3.31,0,0,0-1.71-.74Z"></path><path class="cls-9" d="M1432.85,96.77l3.23,12.08.08.05-3.23-12.07-.08-.06"></path><path class="cls-10" d="M1393.76,74.78c6.67,7.34,15.4,14.22,23.1,20.39,4.63,3.71,9.38,7.26,14.29,10.59,1.58,1.08,3.25,2.08,4.93,3.1l-3.23-12.09q-1.77-1.29-3.54-2.55c-8.12-5.8-16.62-12.3-24.63-18.25Z"></path><polygon class="cls-9" points="1371.29 100.97 1371.3 100.97 1380.56 102.13 1371.29 100.97"></polygon><path class="cls-10" d="M1348.08,71.76a15.65,15.65,0,0,0-5.72,5.52l-.11.18c3.75,3.38,7.52,6.73,11.23,10.13,5.5,5,11.74,9.09,17.81,13.38l9.27,1.16.65-5.21c-2.59-2.47-5-5.1-7.77-7.4-3.36-2.83-6.88-5.49-10.44-8.07s-7.26-5.25-11.09-7.52c-1.27-.75-2.55-1.45-3.83-2.17"></path><path class="cls-11" d="M1346.48,145h0Z"></path><path class="cls-12" d="M1329.09,125A16.07,16.07,0,0,1,1341,144.28l5.44.72h.07a12.55,12.55,0,0,0,.55-2.46c1-8.36-6.1-16.13-16-17.37-.66-.08-1.33-.13-2-.15"></path><path class="cls-12" d="M1423,136.77A16.09,16.09,0,0,1,1434.8,156l5.21.69a13.6,13.6,0,0,0,.55-2.47c1-8.36-5.91-16.11-15.54-17.32-.68-.08-1.36-.13-2-.15"></path><path class="cls-13" d="M1341.27,142.58a16,16,0,1,1-13.89-17.87,16,16,0,0,1,13.89,17.87"></path><path class="cls-2" d="M1321.08,148.59a9.09,9.09,0,1,1,12.31-3.69,9.09,9.09,0,0,1-12.31,3.69"></path><path class="cls-14" d="M1320.23,145.19a5.31,5.31,0,0,0,3.5,3.13,8.89,8.89,0,0,0,1.78.26l.76,0a5.86,5.86,0,0,0,.94-.06,5.24,5.24,0,0,0,3.9-2.85,7.22,7.22,0,0,1-4.47,1.39h-.45a14.35,14.35,0,0,1-3.61-.71c-.43-.13-2.16-.68-2.35-1.17"></path><path class="cls-13" d="M1435.1,154.31a16,16,0,1,1-13.89-17.86,16,16,0,0,1,13.89,17.86"></path><path class="cls-2" d="M1414.92,160.32a9.08,9.08,0,1,1,12.3-3.68,9.07,9.07,0,0,1-12.3,3.68"></path><path class="cls-14" d="M1414.06,156.93a5.33,5.33,0,0,0,3.5,3.13,8.21,8.21,0,0,0,1.78.25c.25,0,.51,0,.76,0a7.57,7.57,0,0,0,1-.06,5.26,5.26,0,0,0,3.89-2.85,7.21,7.21,0,0,1-4.46,1.39l-.46,0a14.79,14.79,0,0,1-3.61-.7c-.43-.14-2.16-.68-2.35-1.17"></path><path class="cls-12" d="M1368.28,108.85a1.64,1.64,0,0,0-1.63,1.44l-.06.45a1.66,1.66,0,0,0,1.43,1.84l5.36.67h.21a1.64,1.64,0,0,0,1.63-1.44l.06-.45a1.66,1.66,0,0,0-1.43-1.84l-5.37-.67h-.2"></path><polygon class="cls-4" points="1397.57 161.91 1396.83 150.81 1401.56 150.29 1403.75 157.78 1405.87 156.49 1405.35 166.06 1400.5 167.27 1397.57 161.91"></polygon><polygon class="cls-3" points="1463.39 224.55 1422.33 210.25 1406.61 162.88 1397.13 165.76 1403.3 225.81 1449.59 254.59 1463.39 224.55"></polygon><path class="cls-15" d="M1361.5,274.9a5.12,5.12,0,0,1,4.47,2.64,11.81,11.81,0,0,1,1.38,5.24,36.16,36.16,0,0,1-.07,6.58,9.22,9.22,0,0,1-1,3.63,3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3,2,5.8,5.8,0,0,1-2.47-.71,3.22,3.22,0,0,1-1.46-1.07,3.27,3.27,0,0,1-.35-1.49c-.22-3.52-3.29-16.46,2.46-16.85"></path><path class="cls-6" d="M1365.28,279a3.67,3.67,0,0,0-.36-.6,5.14,5.14,0,0,0-1.92-1.7s-2.4-.53-1.79.1l1.27,1.32-5.39-.09-3.42,2.73.31,5.81,4,4.54c3.23-.52,6.84-.34,7.87-4.16a12.49,12.49,0,0,0,.25-3.51,10.36,10.36,0,0,0-.77-4.44"></path><path class="cls-16" d="M1321.23,213.5l10.41-.45a51.13,51.13,0,0,0-.1-8.3c0,.33,5.59-2.59,6.08-3.26,1.41-1.91,1.58-5.12,2.16-7.4,1.26-4.84,2.44-10.3-.12-14.6-2.66-4.46-8.39-6-13.58-6.12-6.5-.17-13.77,1.73-17.11,7.31-3,5,.79,12.48,1.88,17.82.53,2.63,1.35,5.63,3.79,6.74,1.3.59,2.87.52,4,1.35,2,1.47,1.58,4.6,2.56,6.91"></path><path d="M1298.71,171q-.57-5.39-1.16-10.79a9.4,9.4,0,0,1,.15-4c.72-2.12,2.87-3.44,5-4s4.42-.61,6.61-1.09,4.59-1.55,7-1.44c4.53.2,8,4.4,12.48,5.11,6.2,1,11.89-1.84,15.63,5.45.69,1.34.88,2.89,1.49,4.27.78,1.78,2.21,3.18,3.32,4.78,4.91,7,3.32,17.66-2.62,23.61-2.88,2.88-4.06,5.49-8,6.41,1.82-3.69-.58-18.41-5.56-20.07-1.32-.43-5.28,1.18-6.74,1.39a38.76,38.76,0,0,0-9.42,2.26,47.36,47.36,0,0,1-14.3,3.56,2.41,2.41,0,0,1-1.8-.35,2.47,2.47,0,0,1-.6-1.62q-.72-6.73-1.45-13.47"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1296.09,226.2s-31.79,40.57-47.69,50.44h0a4,4,0,0,0-2.44,1.68,9.1,9.1,0,0,0-1.29,3.53,36,36,0,0,0-.7,6.54,11.8,11.8,0,0,0,.88,5.34,5.11,5.11,0,0,0,4.2,3.06c2.45.06,3.52-2.28,4-5.25,8.47-5.79,31.43-21.68,33.22-25,2.19-4.13,13.7-40.31,13.7-40.31Z"></path><g class="cls-17"><rect class="cls-1" x="1243.94" y="226.2" width="55.99" height="70.66"></rect></g><polygon class="cls-5" points="1376.38 478.83 1377.78 484.69 1367.45 493.34 1360.19 488.88 1364.65 481.62 1374.98 472.96 1376.38 478.83"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="1352.67 297.45 1356.91 315.26 1351.54 398.07 1376.55 476.79 1365.47 481.89 1315.36 391.01 1309.41 361.98 1306.38 300.6 1352.67 297.45"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="1283.26 304.52 1282.37 381.44 1296.86 480.63 1308.01 480.63 1315.05 389.11 1330.31 297.59 1283.26 304.52"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="1307.95 479.3 1307.95 485.33 1295.89 491.36 1289.87 485.33 1295.89 479.3 1307.95 479.3"></polygon><path class="cls-1" d="M1314.86,210a17.46,17.46,0,0,0-6.07.9c-5.64,2.26-10.32,9.77-13,14.91-3.35,6.56-5.61,13.61-8.08,20.53-3.57,10-7.78,19.69-11.47,29.65a157.44,157.44,0,0,1-9.23,21.4c-1.67,3.3-3.32,7-5.64,9.88-2.08,2.6-2.9,5.7-4,8.83a1,1,0,0,0-.08.66.94.94,0,0,0,.44.42,35,35,0,0,0,15.9,5.05c5.46.38,10.45-1.21,15.81-1.66a191,191,0,0,1,19.42-1,152.2,152.2,0,0,1,24.58,2.53c5.4,1,10.91,2.33,15.73,4.91,4.6,2.46,7.89,6,12.56,8.59a2.39,2.39,0,0,0,1.43.42c2.69-.34,2.91-9.8,2.76-16.82-.07-3.34-.23-6.12-.25-7.11-.15-8.95-.85-17.88-1.89-26.77-.92-8-2.11-15.9-3.39-23.83A149.33,149.33,0,0,0,1346.68,218c-1.54-3-3.3-6.31-6.4-7.71a12.14,12.14,0,0,0-5-.85c-.56,0-1.11,0-1.66,0Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1257.3,316.76a.94.94,0,0,0,.44.42,35,35,0,0,0,15.9,5.05c5.46.38,10.45-1.21,15.81-1.66a191,191,0,0,1,19.42-1,152.2,152.2,0,0,1,24.58,2.53c5.4,1,10.91,2.33,15.73,4.91,4.6,2.46,7.89,6,12.56,8.59a2.39,2.39,0,0,0,1.43.42c2.69-.34,2.91-9.8,2.76-16.82-.07-3.34-.23-6.12-.25-7.11-.15-8.95-.85-17.88-1.89-26.77-.92-8-2.11-15.9-3.39-23.83A149.33,149.33,0,0,0,1346.68,218c-1.54-3-3.3-6.31-6.4-7.71a12.14,12.14,0,0,0-5-.85c-.56,0-1.11,0-1.66,0l-18.71.53a17.46,17.46,0,0,0-6.07.9c-5.64,2.26-10.32,9.77-13,14.91-3.35,6.56-5.61,13.61-8.08,20.53-3.57,10-7.78,19.69-11.47,29.65a157.44,157.44,0,0,1-9.23,21.4c-1.67,3.3-3.32,7-5.64,9.88-2.08,2.6-2.9,5.7-4,8.83A1,1,0,0,0,1257.3,316.76Z"></path><path class="cls-18" d="M1324.32,244a51.41,51.41,0,0,0,.77,10.57q4.59,32,9.19,64.08l-50.24-.44q.92-12,1.82-24a112.49,112.49,0,0,1,1.87-15.31c1.74-8.12,5.25-15.76,8.73-23.34l19.29-42a5.49,5.49,0,0,1,1.34-2.06,5.64,5.64,0,0,1,2.78-1c4.79-.83,10.2-1.53,15-.83,1.2,4.38-3.24,12-4.88,16.07-2.39,5.93-5.25,11.81-5.68,18.27"></path><path class="cls-19" d="M1353.53,349.82H1262a10.89,10.89,0,0,1-10.88-10.89v-61.7A10.88,10.88,0,0,1,1262,266.34h91.56a10.89,10.89,0,0,1,10.89,10.89v61.7a10.9,10.9,0,0,1-10.89,10.89"></path><path class="cls-19" d="M1332.57,261.8v-16a2.93,2.93,0,0,0-3.06-2.67h-44.13a2.93,2.93,0,0,0-3.06,2.67v16a4.58,4.58,0,0,0-4.45,4.58h15a4.59,4.59,0,0,0-4.41-4.58V248.47h38v13.29h-.31a4.58,4.58,0,0,0-4.58,4.58h15a4.59,4.59,0,0,0-4-4.54"></path><path class="cls-20" d="M1364.42,335h0v3.92a10.89,10.89,0,0,1-9.75,10.83v.07a10.78,10.78,0,0,0,9.75-10.73Zm-113.55,6.31c0,4.13,3.56,8.56,7.7,8.56h24.16v-.06H1262a10.89,10.89,0,0,1-10.31-7.4l-.57,0Z"></path><path class="cls-21" d="M1354.67,349.76a10.74,10.74,0,0,1-1.14.06H1321.6v.06h32a8.94,8.94,0,0,0,1-.05Z"></path><polygon class="cls-21" points="1282.73 349.82 1282.73 349.88 1321.59 349.88 1321.6 349.82 1282.73 349.82"></polygon><path class="cls-22" d="M1364.42,323.14a46.14,46.14,0,0,1-9.65,10.18,36.81,36.81,0,0,1-12.89,6.15,136.08,136.08,0,0,1-19.74,3.54,214,214,0,0,1-23.18,1.14c-15.76,0-31.54-1.25-47.3-1.73a10.89,10.89,0,0,0,10.31,7.4h91.56a10.74,10.74,0,0,0,1.14-.06,10.89,10.89,0,0,0,9.75-10.83V323.14Z"></path><path class="cls-18" d="M1334,299.69h-20.14V279.55a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1.38-1.38h-11.44a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1.38,1.38v20.14h-20.13a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1.39,1.38v11.44a1.3,1.3,0,0,0,.4,1,1.27,1.27,0,0,0,1,.41h20.13V334a1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1.38,1.38h11.44a1.38,1.38,0,0,0,1.38-1.38V313.89H1334a1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1.38-1.38V301.07a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1.38-1.38"></path><path class="cls-16" d="M1245.67,292.07a5.38,5.38,0,0,0,.31.64,4.92,4.92,0,0,0,1.75,1.87s2.34.76,1.79.07l-1.13-1.44,5.35.61,3.66-2.4.24-5.81-3.5-4.89c-3.27.21-6.84-.32-8.22,3.39a12.62,12.62,0,0,0-.59,3.47,10.39,10.39,0,0,0,.34,4.49"></path><polygon class="cls-16" points="1271 232.53 1279.4 226.79 1277.11 223.09 1270.48 225.75 1270.2 223.49 1263.61 229.28 1265.48 233.45 1271 232.53"></polygon><path class="cls-1" d="M1214.07,243c-3.24-1.11-4.76-13.8-7.48-15.72-.8-.56-1.8,1.39-2.83,3.34s-2,3.65-2.83,3.41a11.81,11.81,0,0,0-5.42,0,20.55,20.55,0,0,0-12.52,8c-1.46,2-3.61,6.34-1.92,8.8,1.34,1.93,2.9,6.81,5.1,7.75,5.46,2.35,21.82,6.8,30.5,6.69,0,0,11.32-6.7,17.57-9.55,2.83-1.29,34.68-19.26,34.23-20.65l-3.29-8.47c0-.09-.19-.14-.44-.14-2.33,0-13.3,4.16-24.46,8.31C1228.3,239.2,1216.09,243.66,1214.07,243Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1181.07,250.8c1.34,1.93,2.9,6.81,5.1,7.75,5.46,2.35,21.82,6.8,30.5,6.69,0,0,11.32-6.7,17.57-9.55,2.83-1.29,34.68-19.26,34.23-20.65l-3.29-8.47c0-.09-.19-.14-.44-.14-2.33,0-13.3,4.16-24.46,8.31-12,4.46-24.19,8.92-26.21,8.24-3.24-1.11-4.76-13.8-7.48-15.72-.8-.56-1.8,1.39-2.83,3.34s-2,3.65-2.83,3.41a11.81,11.81,0,0,0-5.42,0,20.55,20.55,0,0,0-12.52,8C1181.53,244,1179.38,248.34,1181.07,250.8Z"></path><path class="cls-23" d="M1199.68,187.78l-.56,0c-8.94.43-19.75,12.16-26,19.08-16.18,17.87-27.48,38.35-35.94,61.24-4.55,12.33-8.57,24.86-12.34,37.46-1,3.48-8.35,35.31-10.13,35.54,18.19-2.33,36.5-4.14,54.61-2.89s36.13,5.7,51.66,15.26c8-40.86,13.82-83.16,15.75-124.56.23-5,1-10.06.52-15-.54-5.66-3.33-8.22-6.5-12.52a28.89,28.89,0,0,0-3.51-4.18c-6.71-6.15-17.25-9.49-26.36-9.49C1200.46,187.76,1200.07,187.76,1199.68,187.78Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1114.69,341.12c18.19-2.33,36.5-4.14,54.61-2.89s36.13,5.7,51.66,15.26c8-40.86,13.82-83.16,15.75-124.56.23-5,1-10.06.52-15-.54-5.66-3.33-8.22-6.5-12.52a28.89,28.89,0,0,0-3.51-4.18c-6.71-6.15-17.25-9.49-26.36-9.49-.4,0-.79,0-1.18,0l-.56,0c-8.94.43-19.75,12.16-26,19.08-16.18,17.87-27.48,38.35-35.94,61.24-4.55,12.33-8.57,24.86-12.34,37.46C1123.78,309.06,1116.47,340.89,1114.69,341.12Z"></path><polygon class="cls-16" points="1136.23 326.56 1155.16 403.37 1155.58 459.98 1164.77 461.97 1168.36 409.31 1177.38 312.89 1136.23 326.56"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="1164.89 463.56 1166.37 469.3 1165.07 480.56 1157.62 480.58 1154.83 464.29 1155.7 461.57 1164.89 463.56"></polygon><polygon class="cls-16" points="1208.49 318.07 1210.16 384.44 1201.3 478.18 1192.23 478.85 1188.97 392.91 1170.5 315 1208.49 318.07"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="1201.02 476.62 1213.23 483.1 1212.27 488.81 1190.68 486.17 1191.72 477.95 1201.02 476.62"></polygon><polygon class="cls-7" points="1211.15 326.64 1217.3 403.32 1211.04 455.91 1186.47 454.51 1182.09 394.73 1171.47 329.54 1173.12 319.39 1208.53 319.91 1211.15 326.64"></polygon><polygon class="cls-7" points="1173.9 397.74 1171.01 452.74 1149.65 451.64 1150.09 399.48 1136.62 333.98 1139.69 315.67 1175.61 317.9 1173.9 397.74"></polygon><path class="cls-18" d="M1215.61,333c-21.92-3.78-57.43-12.93-79.34-16.71,11.47-38.08,29.72-80.38,51-113.82,3.86-6.07,8.69-12.4,15.59-13.84,7.4-1.54,20.38,3.34,21.82,11.61,2.1,12.12-2.27,28.82-3.61,41.06-3,27.71-.17,64.33-5.46,91.7"></path><path class="cls-16" d="M1211.8,161.87c8.24-14.34,26.5-5,27.69,9.32.77,9.45-8.41,19.85-17.91,20.59q-.28,3.41-.86,6.78l-7.21-2c-.74-.2-1.59-.5-1.83-1.23a2.31,2.31,0,0,1,.11-1.37c.43-1.52.87-3,1.3-4.54l-.48-.35c-3.95-3-5.75-8.27-5.52-13.23s2.23-9.69,4.71-14"></path><path d="M1212.33,166.72c-4,3.82-4.35,9.94-4.61,15.19-.24,4.66-.93,7.44-5.87,6.13-2.79-.74-7.76-2-8.94-5.06-.89-2.31,2.39-6.27,4.12-7.62,1.32-1,3.31-.86,4.61-1.92a5.41,5.41,0,0,0,1.22-1.65,28,28,0,0,0,2.88-7.93,28.57,28.57,0,0,1,1.3-5.59c1.08-2.56,4.32-4.5,6.41-6.27,3.9-3.3,12.75-5.81,16,.07a8.1,8.1,0,0,1,.61,4.48,6.64,6.64,0,0,1-.57,2.65c-1.65,3.23-4.87,2.23-7.71,2.69a18.32,18.32,0,0,0-9.41,4.83"></path><path d="M1235.27,179.77c-1,2.37-3.54,4.27-3.29,6.84a11.3,11.3,0,0,0,1.22,3.21,9.1,9.1,0,0,1-1.09,8.92l14,6.68a4.65,4.65,0,0,0,2.21.63c1.66-.1,2.66-1.83,3.35-3.34,1.36-3,2.76-6.2,2.15-9.41-.28-1.49-1-2.88-1.26-4.37-1.33-7.18,7.27-14,4.64-20.82-1.18-3-4.26-4.84-6.34-7.34-3.63-4.37-4.15-10.78-8-14.91-7.38-7.78-21.85-1.41-20.74,9.4.91,8.81,17.33,15,13.24,24.51"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1169,304.74c-8.37-23.31,29.53-114.71,29.53-114.71-38.26,16-75.3,149.48-75.3,149.48l58-2.42S1177.33,328.06,1169,304.74Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1123.19,339.51l58-2.42s-3.9-9-12.27-32.35S1198.49,190,1198.49,190C1160.23,206,1123.19,339.51,1123.19,339.51Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M467.52,68.77s0-.19-.11-.19a.05.05,0,0,0-.05,0c-.11-.11-.16.17-.16.17-2.7,2.85-22.76,22.24-63.53,14.56,0,0-4.25,73.09,20.18,102.2,26.1,31.08,47.66,40.11,47.76,40,.11.08,21.34-9.93,45.52-42.56,22.63-30.53,14.62-103.14,14.62-103.14C491.46,89.74,470.37,71.47,467.52,68.77Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M423.85,185.54c26.1,31.08,47.66,40.11,47.76,40,.11.08,21.34-9.93,45.52-42.56,22.63-30.53,14.62-103.14,14.62-103.14-40.29,9.87-61.38-8.4-64.23-11.1,0,0,0-.19-.11-.19a.05.05,0,0,0-.05,0c-.11-.11-.16.17-.16.17-2.7,2.85-22.76,22.24-63.53,14.56C403.67,83.34,399.42,156.43,423.85,185.54Z"></path><path class="cls-3" d="M526,87.53c-36.56,8.81-55.69-7.45-58.27-9.85,0,0-.06-.25-.15-.15-.1-.09-.15.15-.15.15-2.45,2.55-20.66,19.82-57.65,13,0,0-3.89,65.07,18.27,91,23.66,27.67,43.25,37.43,43.34,37.36s19.34-10.59,41.3-39.65C533.25,152.17,526,87.53,526,87.53"></path><path class="cls-3" d="M467.54,74.14a0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.06.06,0,0,0-.05,0c-.07,0-.1.17-.1.17-2.05,2.13-15.15,14.58-41.06,14.58a91.44,91.44,0,0,1-16.59-1.58s-.25,4.15-.26,10.77l.12,0c.07-4.64.24-7.42.24-7.42a91.34,91.34,0,0,0,16.58,1.58c25.92,0,39-12.45,41.07-14.58,0,0,0-.17.1-.17l.05,0a0,0,0,0,1,0,0c.07,0,.11.17.11.17,2,1.9,14.41,12.45,37.55,12.45A88.32,88.32,0,0,0,526,87.53s.31,2.77.62,7.4l.1,0c-.35-6.61-.82-10.74-.82-10.74a88.27,88.27,0,0,1-20.72,2.59c-23.14,0-35.51-10.54-37.55-12.45,0,0,0-.16-.11-.16"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M505.3,90.13c-23.15,0-35.51-10.55-37.55-12.45,0,0,0-.17-.11-.17a0,0,0,0,0,0,0l-.05,0c-.07,0-.1.17-.1.17-2.05,2.13-15.15,14.58-41.07,14.58a91.34,91.34,0,0,1-16.58-1.58s-.17,2.78-.24,7.42a94.69,94.69,0,0,0,15,1.25c27.14,0,40.86-13,43-15.27,0,0,0-.18.11-.18l0,0,.05,0c.07,0,.11.17.11.17,2.14,2,15.1,13,39.33,13a91,91,0,0,0,19.39-2.18c-.31-4.63-.62-7.4-.62-7.4A88.32,88.32,0,0,1,505.3,90.13Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M409.8,90.68s-.17,2.78-.24,7.42a94.69,94.69,0,0,0,15,1.25c27.14,0,40.86-13,43-15.27,0,0,0-.18.11-.18l0,0,.05,0c.07,0,.11.17.11.17,2.14,2,15.1,13,39.33,13a91,91,0,0,0,19.39-2.18c-.31-4.63-.62-7.4-.62-7.4a88.32,88.32,0,0,1-20.72,2.6c-23.15,0-35.51-10.55-37.55-12.45,0,0,0-.17-.11-.17a0,0,0,0,0,0,0l-.05,0c-.07,0-.1.17-.1.17-2.05,2.13-15.15,14.58-41.07,14.58A91.34,91.34,0,0,1,409.8,90.68Z"></path><path class="cls-19" d="M515.61,105.87c-27.62,6.77-45.41-6.34-47.36-8.19,0,0,0-.19-.12-.11-.07-.08-.1.11-.1.11-1.86,2-18.73,16-46.68,10.71,0,0,.21,49.39,17,69.34,17.89,21.32,32.67,27.51,32.74,27.45s14.63-6.81,31.21-29.18c15.51-20.93,13.35-70.13,13.35-70.13"></path><polygon class="cls-16" points="474.1 227.94 469.69 223.78 469.62 218.44 468.48 217.88 467.74 219.26 466.41 214.84 463.29 212.77 458.64 214.54 455.96 218.94 458.21 223.37 463.17 226.6 468.95 232.56 474.1 227.94"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="580.63 476.49 581.81 481.89 572.48 489.58 566.05 485.32 570.13 478.78 579.46 471.09 580.63 476.49"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="520.33 476.64 520.33 482.18 509.25 487.73 503.7 482.18 509.25 476.64 520.33 476.64"></polygon><path class="cls-16" d="M527.58,222.81l9.54-.93a48.54,48.54,0,0,0-.51-7.62c2.65-.93,5.72-2.32,6.18-5.1a7.78,7.78,0,0,0-.15-2.63l-1.85-10.82a9.71,9.71,0,0,0-1.12-3.6c-1.19-1.88-3.5-2.7-5.68-3.08-5.59-1-11.67.22-16,3.87a8.6,8.6,0,0,0-2.71,3.56c-.79,2.19-.2,4.6.38,6.85.54,2.08,1.09,4.16,1.63,6.23.62,2.39,1.52,5.11,3.82,6,1.22.47,2.67.34,3.77,1,2,1.24,1.68,4.14,2.7,6.22"></path><path d="M496.5,186.77a31.06,31.06,0,0,1,.78-7.23c.85-3.87,5.42-5.61,9.37-5.89,8.55-.59,16.79-4.46,25.14-1.47,4.77,1.7,11.17,2.11,15.49,4.52a12.78,12.78,0,0,1,4.36,4.32,19.18,19.18,0,0,1,0,20.3,27,27,0,0,1-3,3.76c-2.25,2.44-4.95,5.45-8,6.35-.07-2.77,2.47-11.5.34-13.77-3.37-3.61-11-2.37-15.19-1.48-4.57,1-8.65,4.19-13.18,4.87-3.26.5-7.42-1.11-10.19-2.8-4.34-2.64-5.79-7-5.9-11.48"></path><polygon class="cls-16" points="499.68 284.54 493.3 286.56 488.1 283.75 486.95 284.55 487.87 286.01 482.9 284.92 479.22 286.81 478.42 292.26 481.24 297.2 486.73 297.42 492.51 294.37 501.37 291.99 499.68 284.54"></polygon><path class="cls-24" d="M552,293c7.24-1.57,5.62-22.94,5.58-27.87,0-6-.3-11.9-.73-17.83-.37-5,.2-9.49-6.33-9.58h-.33c-3.87,0-7.55.88-11.36,1.26-1.63,10.63.39,21.81-1.2,32.6-.55,3.72-1.62,4.05-5.52,5-2.67.65-5.43.78-8.1,1.41l-29.74,7s.26,12.61.27,13C494.5,297,546.79,294.17,552,293Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M524,278l-29.74,7s.26,12.61.27,13c0-1.07,52.27-3.85,57.46-5,7.24-1.57,5.62-22.94,5.58-27.87,0-6-.3-11.9-.73-17.83-.37-5,.2-9.49-6.33-9.58h-.33c-3.87,0-7.55.88-11.36,1.26-1.63,10.63.39,21.81-1.2,32.6-.55,3.72-1.62,4.05-5.52,5C529.42,277.25,526.66,277.38,524,278Z"></path><polygon class="cls-6" points="419.08 234.12 422.75 230.66 422.81 226.22 423.76 225.75 424.38 226.9 425.48 223.22 428.08 221.5 431.95 222.97 434.17 226.63 432.3 230.32 428.18 233.01 423.36 237.96 419.08 234.12"></polygon><polygon class="cls-1" points="399.7 253.04 372.88 227.06 368.71 258.12 401.36 274.3 427.05 235.79 420.24 228.69 399.7 253.04"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="330.63 472.4 330.19 476.79 338.16 482.26 342.82 478.41 339.05 473.48 331.07 468.01 330.63 472.4"></polygon><polygon class="cls-6" points="330.83 338.17 329.48 351.51 341.44 397.32 330.33 470.93 338.51 473.74 360.06 401.88 363.49 380.97 363.36 336.71 330.83 338.17"></polygon><polygon class="cls-6" points="393.71 353.03 376.51 476.38 368.69 476.38 367.29 397.32 353.06 341.82 393.71 353.03"></polygon><polygon class="cls-5" points="368.74 475.4 368.74 479.84 377.19 484.27 381.42 479.84 377.19 475.4 368.74 475.4"></polygon><path class="cls-1" d="M377.35,238.45c-1-4-.86-8.78-2.85-12a7,7,0,0,0-2.58-2.51c-2.81-1.59-6.29-2.1-10-2.1-6.51,0-13.7,1.58-19.07,1.58-2.49,26.21-9.38,51.2-13.82,76.94q-7.08,41-16,81.69c-.25,1.13,12.71,1,20.38.88,2.69-.05,4.73-.09,5.32-.08,22.88.38,52.83.3,74.91-6.61-14.09-37.83-19.23-78.54-30.33-117.35C381.42,252,379.11,245.32,377.35,238.45Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M313.09,382c-.25,1.13,12.71,1,20.38.88,2.69-.05,4.73-.09,5.32-.08,22.88.38,52.83.3,74.91-6.61-14.09-37.83-19.23-78.54-30.33-117.35-1.95-6.81-4.26-13.53-6-20.4-1-4-.86-8.78-2.85-12a7,7,0,0,0-2.58-2.51c-2.81-1.59-6.29-2.1-10-2.1-6.51,0-13.7,1.58-19.07,1.58-2.49,26.21-9.38,51.2-13.82,76.94Q322,341.33,313.09,382Z"></path><path class="cls-5" d="M364.12,187.73a15.43,15.43,0,0,1,11,12.91,13.58,13.58,0,0,0-3-22,15.73,15.73,0,0,0-7.57,9.17Z"></path><path class="cls-6" d="M375.9,195.49c-3-15.8-22.73-13.07-28.4-.28-3.22,7.28.16,17.58,6.6,22.64.14,1.4.32,5.26,1.39,6.2s4.81,0,6.24-.29a2.13,2.13,0,0,0,1.09-.49,4.15,4.15,0,0,0,.43-2.4,13,13,0,0,0,3.22-.63c4.59-1.51,7.92-5.76,9.29-10.39s1-9.62.14-14.36"></path><path class="cls-7" d="M347.08,274.31a10.53,10.53,0,0,1-1.25-3.46,10.15,10.15,0,0,1,.76-5.93,1.67,1.67,0,0,1,2.11-.92,1.63,1.63,0,0,1,.91,2.1,7.09,7.09,0,0,0-.12,5.76,7.11,7.11,0,0,1,1.23-.55c1.56-.53,3.9-1.12,5.07.43,1.32,1.75.13,3.86-1.59,4.71a5.66,5.66,0,0,1-4.42.42c0,2,.57,3,2.46,3.56,1.16.34,4,.64,4.93-.45.59-.71.54-2.84.76-3.79a37.45,37.45,0,0,1,2.59-7.6,42.41,42.41,0,0,1,9.6-13c9-8.39,20.8-13.28,32.77-15.44q1-.18,2-.33a64,64,0,0,1,23.81.65,22.68,22.68,0,0,1,6.39-6.77c5.77-4,13.77-4.8,19.9-1.42-4.81,5.62-8.75,13.68-9.39,15a51.12,51.12,0,0,1,17.76,18.46l.26.47,9,1.42s3.35,17.58,1.36,22.89c0,0-7,2.87-11.2,4a48.64,48.64,0,0,1-15.5,19c-.46.35-.93.69-1.41,1l2.18,14S437.24,334,431.48,333l-4.81-9.37a69.77,69.77,0,0,1-8.51,1.88,80.15,80.15,0,0,1-10.22.92l-1.76,10.5c-5.19,2.68-17.08.77-17.08.77l-2.18-14c-15.45-4.84-26.83-15.93-29.42-32.64a41.2,41.2,0,0,1-.44-4.21,11.35,11.35,0,0,1-7-2.31,8.88,8.88,0,0,1-3.07-4.76c-.46-1.72-.76-3.76.07-5.41"></path><path class="cls-25" d="M425,242.22l-1.1,5.33s-16.5-2-32.57,5l-4.12-3s14.06-13.39,37.79-7.36"></path><path class="cls-2" d="M462.63,298.88c-.49.35-1,.69-1.51,1L459,301.27a51.66,51.66,0,0,1-11.74,12.2c-.46.35-.93.69-1.41,1l.1.63c1.47-.92,2.88-1.88,4.23-2.9a51.07,51.07,0,0,0,12.48-13.35"></path><path class="cls-25" d="M360.45,290c3.67,22.93,23.95,35.21,48.54,35.21a78.58,78.58,0,0,0,12.09-.95,66,66,0,0,0,24.84-9.1l-.1-.63c.48-.34.95-.68,1.41-1A51.66,51.66,0,0,0,459,301.27c-11.05,6.9-23,12.48-36.16,13.78-2.33.23-4.68.34-7,.34a86.73,86.73,0,0,1-22-3c-12.55-3.32-24.69-9.91-32.2-20.8-.38-.54-.76-1.08-1.11-1.64"></path><path class="cls-2" d="M466.65,265.56s.17.41.43,1.15l.36.06c-.25-.42-.51-.82-.79-1.21m3.21,26.51-1.89.7,1.87-.6a.65.65,0,0,0,0-.1"></path><path class="cls-25" d="M467.08,266.71c1.42,4,5.44,17.64-1.49,26.82l2.38-.76,1.89-.7c.32-1.35,3.49-15.5-2.42-25.3Z"></path><polygon class="cls-6" points="355.41 282.62 360.66 284.34 364.97 282.07 365.92 282.74 365.14 283.94 369.26 283.07 372.28 284.67 372.89 289.17 370.53 293.23 365.99 293.36 361.25 290.8 353.96 288.76 355.41 282.62"></polygon><path class="cls-1" d="M337.61,270.2c-.18-2.89.5-5.75,1-8.6a70.59,70.59,0,0,0-.62-27.36c-.53-2.42-1.69-3.36-3.12-3.36-3.83,0-9.61,6.75-10.55,9.68-1.43,4.46-1,9.32-1.38,13.93q-.7,9.28-.66,18.61c0,3.93-1,13.21,3.18,15.46a11.46,11.46,0,0,0,3.66,1c2,.32,25.54,3.29,25.91,2.13l3.26-10.27c-4.91-1-12.25-1.45-16.75-4.49A8.41,8.41,0,0,1,337.61,270.2Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M325.46,288.56a11.46,11.46,0,0,0,3.66,1c2,.32,25.54,3.29,25.91,2.13l3.26-10.27c-4.91-1-12.25-1.45-16.75-4.49a8.41,8.41,0,0,1-3.93-6.75c-.18-2.89.5-5.75,1-8.6a70.59,70.59,0,0,0-.62-27.36c-.53-2.42-1.69-3.36-3.12-3.36-3.83,0-9.61,6.75-10.55,9.68-1.43,4.46-1,9.32-1.38,13.93q-.7,9.28-.66,18.61C322.29,277,321.32,286.31,325.46,288.56Z"></path><path d="M346.71,258.21a3.58,3.58,0,0,0,.45,0c3.49-.59,9.07-1.72,10.69-5.39s-1.28-10.58-1.77-14.48c-.74-5.94-1-11.93-1.27-17.9-.26-5.39,1.67-10.7,4.48-15.29s6.51-8.59,10.13-12.58c1.51-1.66,3.08-3.43,3.54-5.62A8.34,8.34,0,0,0,370.9,180a11.69,11.69,0,0,0-9.11-4.45c-13.06-.31-22.87,7.41-26.58,20.16-5.31,18.28,1.32,35.71.34,53.89a17.42,17.42,0,0,1-2.94,8.74c.46-.69,11.29,0,14.1-.14"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M419.58,186.2a20.76,20.76,0,0,0-3.22.26,20,20,0,1,0,3.22-.26Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M422.21,222.68a16.24,16.24,0,0,1-2.68.22,16.73,16.73,0,1,1,2.68-.22Z"></path><path class="cls-8" d="M414.88,213.34c-.22-.11-.3-.4-.39-.66a1.05,1.05,0,0,1,.77-1.42c1-.28,2.14.33,3.12.62A5.8,5.8,0,0,0,421,212a3.65,3.65,0,0,0,2.22-1.07,2.31,2.31,0,0,0,.59-2,1.89,1.89,0,0,0-1-1.55,4.41,4.41,0,0,0-2.5-.12l-.76.12a6.79,6.79,0,0,1-4.45-.51,4.1,4.1,0,0,1-2-3.17,4.17,4.17,0,0,1,.91-3.6,6.11,6.11,0,0,1,3.84-1.82,6.84,6.84,0,0,1,2.21,0c1.6.25,4.31,1.09,4,2.69-.34,1.82-3.39-.27-4.39-.53a4.86,4.86,0,0,0-2-.05,3.1,3.1,0,0,0-2,1,2.23,2.23,0,0,0-.52,1.86,1.58,1.58,0,0,0,1,1.35,8.94,8.94,0,0,0,3.57,0,6.85,6.85,0,0,1,4.36.55,4.31,4.31,0,0,1,1.85,3.23,4.67,4.67,0,0,1-.9,3.79,5.71,5.71,0,0,1-3.72,1.94,10.77,10.77,0,0,1-1.77.1,12,12,0,0,1-4.74-.9"></path><path class="cls-8" d="M421.32,217.57h0a1.14,1.14,0,0,1-1.21-1l-3.15-20.29a1.15,1.15,0,0,1,.84-1.36h0a1.13,1.13,0,0,1,1.22,1l3.15,20.3a1.14,1.14,0,0,1-.85,1.35"></path></svg></mat-icon>
```

Has anyone ever come across a similar issue? Does anyone have any advice on why this might be happening? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like a bug in the SVG renderer.

Comment: @Henry We are adding it in as a mat-icon. I have added a snippet to show what it looks like in the code. Note that this is built up using a string of utils and services, which I can try and expand on it it might help us find a solution.

Comment: Has you try registring the mat-icon https://material.angular.io/components/icon/examples or directly put directly the svg code in the .html?

Comment: @Eliseo those are good suggestions. At the moment we are using several cases to select which icon to use on which page, so it is programmatically generated, but then it selects one of several SVG files, so I might not be able to place it directly into the HTML. I'll look into the material.angular.io approach though thanks!